# eclipse plugin: set view name by ID programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i created a eclipse plugin which can query the view name through a java class programatically as follows:

```
IViewDescriptor descr = window.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().find(viewID);
    System.out.println("View Label: " + descr.getLabel());
```

But how can i set the label (change label name) to the same view ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for another plugin to change the name.

In a view part you can call `setPartName(new name)` but this is a `protected` method so it is only available to derived classes.